# git push heroku master error: Could not read

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I tried looking through some `git push heroku master` errors on this website, but I couldn't find one with my specific problem. Hopefully you guys can help me.

When I run `git push heroku master`

```
error: Could not read 6f2abfc273544edc8fa8fbf18837a9ecec606bb2
fatal: bad tree object 6f2abfc273544edc8fa8fbf18837a9ecec606bb2
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/still-harbor-74893.git'
fatal: write error: Bad file descriptor`
```

I've read that Heroku sets a hard limit on file sizes, is that the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your github file is corrupted or not. Or maybe one of the file is corrupted. I can't think of anything else that might be the problem here.

Comment: I'm sorry but how do I check if my files are corrupted or not?

Comment: `On branch master.
     nothing to commit, working tree clean`

I don't think anything is corrupted? What should I be trying next?

Comment: I think its because of large file/commit size. So you might wanna reduce it and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that your repository/current directory is broken. If you think that your current working directory contains uncorrupted files, then you can always re-initialize Git in your working directory. For example:

```
rm -rf .git
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'Re-initialize repo.'
```

And then try to push to heroku.

Comment: I tried running the commands you told me about, but now I'm getting


      `fatal: 'heroku' does not appear to be a git repository
      fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

      Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.`

Oh and all my branches are gone as well when I check with `git branch`